# Connect to a SQLite database outside /var/www

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu

Current code:

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/usr/local/teamspeak3/ts3server.sqlitedb';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
$query =  "SELECT * FROM clients";
foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row)
{
    echo $row[0];
}
```

I am trying to open this database and echo out the information. The problem is that the website is located at /var/www and it won't let me access any folder above that. I can't access folders like /usr or even /var/backups.

Does anyone know how I can access this file anyway? I can't move the file because it gets constantly updated by TeamSpeak.

Comment: what does error log says ?

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP preventing access from outside your sandboxed environment?

Ask your administrator to place a symlink to the actual database into a folder you can access to work around the security restriction.

This is in place to prevent a compromised (or just plain buggy) page from providing access to a client to databases that they should not be able to see.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is quite Linux generic.

1. Get access to error logs.
2. Find the **php.ini** for scripts You run on a web-server.
3. Find directive `open_basedir` in this file.
4. Add `/usr/local/teamspeak3/` path.
5. Check the web-server has read access to **/usr/local/teamspeak3/ts3server.sqlitedb**
6. Restart web-server.
7. If it doesn't work, check error logs.